# How to write a XML file using dataset having multiple table with the help of XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am using a dataset and storing a Query result into that data set.
My Query id is like that

```
String Query = @"SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
                 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
                 SELECT * FROM TABLE3;";
```

I am using following thing

```
XmlDocument relationSheepDoc = new XmlDocument();
    StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(sWriter);
    DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet("RelationSheeps");
     oDataSet = sql.ExecuteSqlDataSet(Query);
    string fileContent = string.Empty;
       for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            oDataSet.Tables[i].WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            fileContent = sWriter.ToString();               

        }
        relationSheepDoc.LoadXml(fileContent);
        xmlWriter.Close();

        return relationSheepDoc;
```

It write only first table and generates Exception 
How can i write All three table in the same XML file?
Help me...

Answer (score 0):

You should write the entire DataSet at once, like this:

```
oDataSet.WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```